# WordPress, как спрятать WP admin menu при логине пользователя

Tags: wordpress

у меня есть код входа в систему пользователя

```
if ($_POST['organization_login']) {
        $login_data = array();
        $login_data['user_login'] = $_POST['organization_email'];
        $login_data['user_password'] = $_POST['password'];
        $login_data['remember'] = true;

        $result = wp_signon($login_data, false);

        if (!is_wp_error($result)) {
            wp_set_current_user($result->ID, $result->user_login);
            wp_set_auth_cookie($result->ID, true, false);
            do_action('wp_login', $result->user_login);
            header('Location:' . $url);
            exit();
        }
    }
```

Все работает отлично, но при входе у меня виднеется админ панель

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

как её скрыть от залогиненого пользователя?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если речь о том, чтобы скрыть админ-панель на фронте, то так:

```
function show_admin_bar_filter() {
    return false;
}

add_filter( 'show_admin_bar', 'show_admin_bar_filter' );
```

В административной части сайта это не работает.